# Does the pitch fall before 子?

Tags: pitch-accent

I swear I hear "その\子" ”この\子たち” but my pitch perception is not that good and it might drop after 子 but I can't really tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, この子・その子・あの子 all have an accent on の (〇の＼こ).

This doesn't generalise to "子 places an accent on the previous mora" (neither are この・その・あの odaka). It's just that この子 etc. have each kind of become their own word, with its own unique accent (and they don't simply equal この・その・あの + 子).

Comment: Same as あの人, I guess it's been lexicalised into special cases.

Comment: Yep. Other similar examples that come to mind are 世の中、髪の毛、目の前. Lots of lexicalised AのBs.

Comment: My dictionary seems to have the downstep of 目の前 on the first mora of まえ — is this incorrect, or perhaps an alternative?

Comment: It’s めのまえ【LHHL】.

Comment: @jogloran Your dictionary is right (as aguijonazo kindly confirmed). I didn't mean to imply that the accent will always be on the の in these phrases, if that's what you were thinking — the common denominator among the examples I brought up is that they have an *unexpected* PA pattern (you would expect めのまえ{HLLL} based on 目+の+前).